# Fetching/selecting bottom N elements is messing up the value of time stamp in result set (because of time zone I think)

Tags: java, datetime, jpa, spring-data-jpa, timezone-offset

I spent almost a day trying to fetch bottom 10 rows from a table that has few hundred thousand rows in **multiple ways**. But timestamp in result set is always messed up by 7 hours (that is the time difference between UTC and my local)

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xyz(
  id timestamp NOT NULL, 
  name varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id,name )
);
```

Bottom 10 entries in db after running **select  * from xyz order by id desc limit 10;**

```
 2020-05-12 12:00:00+00  
 2020-05-12 12:00:00+00  
 2020-05-12 11:59:00+00  
 2020-05-12 11:58:00+00  
 2020-05-12 11:58:00+00  
 2020-05-12 11:58:00+00  
 2020-05-12 11:57:00+00  
 2020-05-12 11:56:00+00  
 2020-05-12 11:56:00+00  
 2020-05-12 11:55:00+00
```

I tried following 3 ways of selecting bottom 10 rows from DB. Also I always get null list if I select within a range.

```
List<xyz> findTop10ByOrderByIdDesc();
List<xyz> findTop10DistinctByIdBetweenOrderByIdDesc(LocalDateTime now,LocalDateTime after);
List<xyz> findTop10DistinctByIdBetweenOrderByIdDesc(Date now,Date after);
```

Here is POJO for holding the result set of above query

```
public class xyz{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private java.util.Date id;
//private LocalDateTime id
  private String name;

// ...
}
```

but `id` field is always off by 7 hours (for example: 1st element I get is `2020-05-12 05:00:00`)  .  a)How can I fix my code to get right timestamp in POJO (or result set). b) How can I retrieve all the entries within a range (I get null list now). I think both of them are related

Comment: Can you replace the `Date` with an `Instant`? I'm hoping this would increase the chance of it getting handled correctly.

Comment: What's wrong? If I understand correctly, 05:00 in your time zone *is* the same time as 12:00 UTC, so you *are* getting the correct time? What am I missing?

Comment: While the modern `Instant` is better than the poorly designed and long outdated `Date`, I don't think you should use either for an entity ID. `timestamp` in the database neither. How about an auto-incremented ID, for example?

Comment: Which database engine are you using? MySQL? If so, the timestamp in the database  is in UTC, and if `Instant` doesn’t work in the entity class, you should probably use `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: @JensSchauder: if you can post it as answer, I will accept it. Util.Date should not be used at all (java.time is way to go)

Comment: @OleV.V. I am using postgres. I solved it by a)using ```Instant``` instead of ```Date``` and b) parsing timestamp exactly in the format as in DB as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61846147/parsing-timestamp-with-into-date-or-instant-in-java?noredirect=1#comment109392288_61846147

Comment: @OleV.V. Good advice about NOT using timestamp as entity ID. But this is   third party database that sits outside my network (and I issue fetch only queries)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214070/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-mobiledev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.Date` which technically according to the documentation represents a point in time. 
But in reality it is a an awful mixture that gets used for all kinds of stuff.
This results in all kind of weird (and probably plain wrong) stuff happening in the database, the driver and any ORM layers on top of that.

Luckily `java.util.Date` now hasa proper replacement in the [`java.time.*` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).
You are seem to be interested in a point of time: When did an event happen. 
The correct data type for that is `[Instant][1]`.

While I can't promise anything the chances of that being persisted and loaded in the correct way is much bigger.