# Parsing timestamp with '+' into Date or Instant in Java

Tags: java, jodatime

I have timestamp of the format  `2020-05-12 12:00:00+00` . How can I parse into Java.util.Date and Java.time.Instant.
Seemingly basic question, but I suspect it is the source of the problem that I am yet to solve in [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61810380/fetching-selecting-bottom-n-elements-is-messing-up-the-value-of-time-stamp-in-re)

Comment: Why did you tag `jodatime`, then explicit ask about the built-in `java.util.Date` and `java.time.Instant`?

Comment: I agree with you that you should solve the root cause in your other question. If there is one. I have taken a look and am not convinced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 introduced `DateTimeFormatter`. Here is the link to the [DateTimeFormatter Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ssx");
String tsFromDb = "2020-05-12 12:00:00+00";
Instant inst = formatter.parse(tsFromDb, Instant::from);
System.out.println(inst);
```

Output:

> 2020-05-12T12:00:00Z

If you need a `java.util.Date`:

```
Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(inst);
System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

Output in America/Tijuana time zone:

> Tue May 12 05:00:00 PDT 2020

Comment: It's a good suggestion. It's hardly enough for an answer. Link-only answers are not considered true answers here. You may want to explain in just a bit of depth how it helps.

Comment: @rocketman: Great answer and it worked.